# How do I create a printer friendly HTML page?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, printing

How do I change or remove layouts from my application on a specific Rails view to allow my users to have a more enjoyable printing experience? (No navbar, or other extra data)

I have been banging my head against the table for a few hours now trying to figure this out. I have tried using `render layout: false` with no success.

I have tried creating an action like below but it didn't work for me either:

```
def print
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render layout: false } 
  end
end
```

I tried linking to this action by using the following:

`<%= link_to 'Printer Friendly Version', product_path(@product), :action => 'print', target: '_new' %>`

Am I just completely off base here? How can I better approach this obstacle?
I do not want to use PDF or Javascript, I just want to render printer-friendly HTML.

Comment: check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#choosing-layouts-at-runtime

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do it just with CSS like this: See [full article here.](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia2.shtml)

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print{
  body{ background-color:#FFFFFF; background-image:none; color:#000000 }
  #ad{ display:none;}
  #leftbar{ display:none;}
  #contentarea{ width:100%;}
}
</style>
```

It uses a simplified CSS when it detects that the page is being sent to the printer.

[-- W3Schools link --](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp).

Also see [this article](http://envisionic.com/webtips/user_experience/printer_friendly.php):

> Abstract: **How to make printer friendly web pages**
>
> If your web site delivers value to your audience, chances are they are
>   going to want to print pages out. Making sure desktop printers handle
>   your web site well is another aspect of building a great
>   user-experience.
>
> This article takes a quick look at using Cascading Style Sheets to
>   design printed web pages.

Comment: This is a great reference and simple concept. I am now making my print.css stylesheet however I just have to figure out how to apply it when I click my printer friendly link. Thank you!

Comment: @pyRabbit: You don't even need a print-friendly link. If you look at the updated answer you can see that printer-friendly CSS can be automatic when a printer is detected. No other UI is necessary.

Comment: Your updated inline styles worked great for me! I just have to make sure to stay on top of keeping my CSS up-to-date. Thank you!

Comment: If you have a default CSS style sheet just add the definition into it. That will make every page on your site that uses the common style sheet be "printer friendly"

Comment: Great!!! but I keep getting a second page at my preview, any idea??

Comment: All of the above links to the references are DEAD today, 8/9/2021.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd link are still out of order , but your answer helps to print Html in a sensible way.